# Screen shakes when the object moves

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, shake

Hello im working on a project and i got a problem
screen/ground shakes when i moved main object.

Normally when i moved with "w" button i dont get a problem.
But if move while im rotating camera i got the problem.

To see: give a degree like 30 with right mouse button.(do not release button)
and keep w button while rotating object.
you will see the shake at the ground.

I think the problem is about my looat function calculation.

```
gluLookAt(sin(rot*PI/180)*(10-fabs(roty)/4) +movex ,3-(roty/2), cos(rot*PI/180)*(10-(fabs(roty)/4)) +movez , -sin(rot*PI/180)*6 + movex, roty, -cos(rot*PI/180)*6 +movez, 0, 1, 0);
```

Here is the my rotation function. I draw everything after this func.

```
void System::rotater(){

if(mouseStates[2][0]==1 && mx!= savex && mx!=mouseStates[2][1]){
    rot += (mx-mouseStates[2][1]) * 90 / glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)/2;
    if(rot>360)rot-=360;
    if(rot<0)rot= 360+rot;

}


glRotatef(rot,0,1,0);
}
```

And last my move option is here:

```
if(a==87 || a==119){
movex -= sin(rot*PI/180)/3;
movez -= cos(rot*PI/180)/3;
}
```

Comment: Please don't make people download and execute unknown binaries. Supply the full source code through a pastebin or  a repository on gitourious, github, etc. if you must. **BUT NO BINARY EXECUTABLES!**

Comment: Ok, i edited and added full source.

Comment: I think problem is about sinus cosinus functions. 
Because i cant see the shake without them
gluLookAt(movex ,3-(roty/2), movez +5 , movex, roty, movez, 0, 1, 0);

but i need them to follow object from behind.

Answer (score 0):

I've found seen screen shaking issues are commonly to do with the order in which you process events, update objects and the camera, before drawing the scene (or the physics engine is causing it :P). With a high framerate you might not notice small imperfections. You might want to add a Sleep/usleep to help expose these issues. For example, if your camera position is based on the camera rotation, but you update the position before processing the mouse events the camera position/rotation can be a frame out of sync.

This is a good reason to process inputs, movement and rendering in very separate stages.

Your lookAt function does look rather complex. lookAt is very useful when you want a camera that looks-at something, but in this case you're after a camera that looks-from a camera position. This is easier to implement by manually constructing the inverse transformations to position the camera object before drawing the sceene. For example, if you want to move left, translate everything else right (thus inverse)...

```
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(camera.rotX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(camera.rotY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(camera.rotZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(-camera.posX, -camera.posY, -camera.posZ);
```

Comment: I updated before draw but result same.
I thought when i work with many model/object, the camera system that u told will cause lag?. Program will translate all of objects when i moved. Because program translates earth.

Comment: This is how cameras are implemented. The gluLookAt call applies a transform to the modelview matrix in a similar manner - moving all the objects in the scene. This isn't expensive as all those operations are combined into the single 4x4 modelview matrix which is used to transform everything you draw anyway. As for the shaking, I can only speculate there's still an issue with the order in which things are updated and drawn without seeing your main loop structure.